# I cannot delete the icon on toolbar

Tags: java, android, layout

I am new to Android and I copied a sample code from web and build my app on that sample code. But I am trying to delete the image on the top toolbar. I cannot locate where the program puts that image.

here is the screen. I put a red mark on the toolbar I am talking about and I want to remove that smily face on that bar. but I dont want to delete the image, I want to find the code which puts that face there.

[image]

Comment: try to search any "header" layout or "view", inside that there is "ImageView" and it has "ic_launcher" set as source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be located in your manifest file under the `<application>` tag. Here is an example:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Now each of the `="@somewhere/name"` is a pointer. The icon is under *res/drawable*, while the other two will be under *res/values/*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. You must add in the onCreate() method of your activty :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```